# Completely remove lockscreen

Tags: 18.04, lock-screen

I have the vanilla Ubuntu 18 installed on a computer and I'd like to completely disable the lockscreen. But even after disabling it in the settings (see image) it still shows up after "waking" up from the screensaver (blak screen), you just don't have to enter the password anymore. Is there a way to *actually* completely disable it such that it also doesn't show up after coming back from the screensaver (I'd like to keep the blank screen as screensaver)?

[image]

Comment: Please issue this command `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false`. The display screen will no longer lock by itself. That’s it!

Comment: @Marmayogi Thanks a lot, please consider adding it as an answer so that I can accept it!

Comment: I am very glad that your problem was solved! Good Luck, @flawr!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Enable/Disable Lock Screen.

**To disable Lock screen using GUI, just follow this:**

Settings -> Privacy -> Screen Lock -> change '**Automatic Screen Lock**' to '**Off**'

[image]

`Figure-1: Disable screen lock using Settings GUI`

**To disable Lock screen through command line permanently, issue the following commands:**

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen true
```

[image]
`Figure-2: Disable screen lock and "Screen Lock window" is also made inaccessible`

The first command disables `Screen Lock` (refer small red box in figure-2). The second command makes `Screen Lock window` permanently inaccessible and no body can touch it even through `Settings GUI` (refer large red box in figure-2).

**If you are unhappy with the new setting, you can reverse it using following command:**

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled true
```

[image]
`Figure-3: Enables screen lock but "Screen Lock window" is still inaccessible`

This command enables `Screen Lock` again (refer small red box in figure-3). Note that the `Screen Lock window` is still inaccessible (refer large red box in figure-3).

**To enable `Screen Lock window` access by `Settings GUI`**

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen false
```

[image]
`Figure-4: The "Screen Lock window" is now accessible`

After the execution of command, the `Screen Lock window` is now accessible through `Settings GUI` (refer large red box in figure-4).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with it going bland when ALL Possible Settings for this had Lock or Screen saver or timeout set to NEVER.

Screen Going into SLEEP MODE,  or BLACK,  when NOT set to!

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim false

$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false

$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen true
```

---

To make this permanent, you need a gsettings override file...

1. Open a new empty document in gedit, (or other text editor) on your host system.
2. Add the following contents to your file:

   ```
   [org.gnome.desktop.screensaver]
   lock-enabled = false
   [org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power]
   idle-dim = false
   ```
3. Save the file with the following name:

   ```
   90_ubuntu-settings.gschema.override
   ```
4. Move it to the right location (and give root privileges and executable):
5. Open Nautilus (or another file browser) on your host system **WITH/AS ROOT**, and navigate to the directory where you saved the file `90_ubuntu-settings.gschema.override`.
   Cut and Paste it to:

   ```
   /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
   ```
6. Activate it in terminal:

   ```
   $ sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
   ```

I sure hope this helps others, Mark

Comment: Success, either one or all of the three commands sopped it or the new file as I outlined it, but it has definitely stopped going to sleep now ... when set not to!

Answer (score 0):

in Ubuntu 22.04, under Settings>>Privacy>>Screen, you can change the "blank screen delay" timeout to "never" to avoid the screen fading out.

In older versions, maybe the setting for that is under "screen" or some similar other setting related to the display.